# Not a JSON Object

Tags: android, json

i have data from server like this :

```
{
    "error": false,
    "alerts": {
        "code": "200",
        "message": "retrieve success"
    },
    "data": [{
        "incident__task_i_d": "8d37a3f1-d257-4833-9701-4eab0e48076f",
        "address": "Pulo Jahe Motor",
        "task_status": "Completed",
        "incident_i_d": "83eeed0f-4ea4-416b-8721-637e40ac9f72",
        "vehicle_i_d": "36420155-6214-4745-bbf3-7dae7d50ce9c",
        "agent_i_d": "1c3436fd-9338-4910-9686-8c1cd0a33433",
        "dispatched_time": "2016-08-12T08:29:47.89",
        "origin_latitude": "-6.8979664",
        "origin_longitude": "107.6135752",
        "destination_latitude": "-6.198816382772501",
        "destination_longitude": "106.921986633551",
        "created_dt": "2016-08-12T08:29:47.89",
        "departed_time": "2016-08-12T10:13:20.947",
        "arrival_time": "2016-08-12T10:11:14.93",
        "kick_off_time": "2016-08-12T10:13:54.54",
        "finished_time": "2016-08-12T10:14:30.893",
        "incident_reported_dt": "2016-08-11T08:21:34.23"
    }]
}
```

But i want to get value from `array of object` .. like i want to get value from `incident__task_i_d` so how can i get ? 
i have a some code like this :

```
try
            {
                rawContent = new String(content);
                Log.i("TAG", "ALL DATA "+rawContent);

                JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(rawContent).getAsJsonObject();
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(ModelRekap.DATE_FORMAT).create();

                Log.i("haha","masuk list ini");
                JsonArray jaray = json.getAsJsonArray("data");

                listInfoAnda  = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jaray.size(); i++) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "ARRAY " + i);
                    try {
                        JsonElement address = ((JsonObject)jaray.get(i)).get("address");
                        Log.i("ISI rekap address", "" + address.toString());
                        ModelRekap mCoba = gson.fromJson(jaray.get(i), ModelRekap.class);

                        listInfoAnda.add(mCoba);
                        Log.i("TAG","MODEL" + mCoba.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                onFinishRequest(true, rawContent);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                onFinishRequest(false, rawContent);
            }
        }
```

But doesn't work correctly , i have some error like this :

```
08-12 22:31:03.926 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [{"incident__task_i_d":"8d37a3f1-d257-4833-9701-4eab0e48076f","address":"Pulo Jahe Motor","task_status":"Completed","incident_i_d":"83eeed0f-4ea4-416b-8721-637e40ac9f72","vehicle_i_d":"36420155-6214-4745-bbf3-7dae7d50ce9c","agent_i_d":"1c3436fd-9338-4910-9686-8c1cd0a33433","dispatched_time":"2016-08-12T08:29:47.89","origin_latitude":"-6.8979664","origin_longitude":"107.6135752","destination_latitude":"-6.198816382772501","destination_longitude":"106.921986633551","created_dt":"2016-08-12T08:29:47.89","departed_time":"2016-08-12T10:13:20.947","arrival_time":"2016-08-12T10:11:14.93","kick_off_time":"2016-08-12T10:13:54.54","finished_time":"2016-08-12T10:14:30.893","incident_reported_dt":"2016-08-11T08:21:34.23"}]
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:90)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at com.example.fania.cobalagi.api.ApiRekapData$1.onSuccess(ApiRekapData.java:100)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at com.radyalabs.async.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:264)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at com.radyalabs.async.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:134)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-12 22:31:03.931 6111-6111/com.example.fania.cobalagi W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm new in `Android Programming`.

Comment: Which line to getting error ??

Comment: in here  JsonElement address = ((JsonObject)jaray.get(i)).get("address");

Comment: Post this code at you getting `JSONObject jj = jaray.getJSONObject(i);String address = jj.getString("address");Log.e("check ", "Address ... " + address);`

Comment: okee i have solve this problem .. thanks you very much :)

Comment: hmm i don't know for sure , because when i'm run again my android application , that code work correctly.  hehe

Comment: hmm .. What can I do for you??

Comment: i'm sorry , i'm don't understand. can you explain again?

Comment: ohh i see.. wkwkw sure ;) which your app is still doesn't work ??

Comment: hmm what kind of your app ? do you have an error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suggest to use this approach !! i hope this help you :)

```
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject data=jsonParser.parse(rawContent).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("data").get(0)
        .getAsJsonObject();

    String incident= data.get("incident__task_i_d").getAsString();
```

Comment: you are welcome ,  happy to help !! can you validate the response that helped you for a better community ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, you need to know path and index in advance to query json-data.

```
JSONObject response=new JSONObject(rawContent);
JSONArray data=response.getJSONArray("data");
String incident=data.getJSONObject(0).getString("incident__task_i_d");
```